# Magento Add to Compare URL inconsistency for the same product

Tags: magento

I have a 
(1) Magento home page which I've customized to display "New Products", with Add to Compare button.
(2) The pretty standard product listing pages which display based on user filters. Add to compare button is also displayed here.

Both page templates call on getAddToCompareUrl for their respective products. But for some reason the **Add to Compare** URL generated on the **homepage** is different/ missing a chunk and clicking on it does not result in the product getting added to the Compare List. The Add to Compare URL that is generated for the Product listing, however, works just as expected. Here are the "Add to Compare" URLs being generated:

Home Page (Add to compare URL **does not work and looks incomplete as compared to the one generated on product listing)**

```
http://localhost/mg1/index.php/catalog/product_compare/add/product/156/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tZzEvaW5kZXgucGhwLw,,/form_key/ysxqFftqrKpaqGqE/
```

Product Listing (Add to compare URL **works**)

```
  http://localhost/mg1/index.php/catalog/product_compare/add/product/156/uenc/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9tZzEvaW5kZXgucGhwL2xhcmdlLWFwcGxpYW5jZXMvcmVmcmlnZXJhdG9ycy5odG1sP21hbnVmYWN0dXJlcj0yMg,,/form_key/Vh0H6NDCl3wFGSys/
```

If i observe the differences between both URLs, it seens the URL generated on the homepage is missing a huge chunk in the /enc/ section, the /form_key/ is also different on both URLs, although they are for the same product (ID 156).

I had a quick look at the getAddToCompareUrl function where i see it deriving the url enc and form key portions of the URL, (code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\Abstract.php) but without knowing how to debug through the myriad of class calls underneath it, I'm lost.

Help anyone?